# How to send Data from Android App to Samsung Gear (Tizen)

Tags: android, tizen, accessory, tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-mobile-sdk

I am working on a Integrated Samsung Gear Application which needs to fetch data from Android app, which asks user's information such as Name, Age etc..and send this information to the wearable App.
I tried with information on following link but it's not working.
 http://blog.scalac.io/2014/07/30/developing-your-first-galaxy-gear-app.html
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an android service for your android app or you can just integrate the code for sending data from activity to service in the sap service provider app and then fetch data from the service to the wearable app.

Comment: That's what the above link says,,here the problem is how to send the user's data from activity to service

Comment: there are lots of example for that just google it. here is the code download it.        https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9jZ0DG7pnbDU01Eb2s3MzJaWjQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @AbhishekSharma Do we need to develop an Tison os app for the watch ? Or is there any  way to communicate with the watch and our android app. I want to show some messages in Galaxy watch from my android app.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use "Samsung Accessory Protocol"

I added some references pointers on this page :

https://wiki.tizen.org/wiki/Wearable#API